# For Looping in VB6

Tags: vb6

I have a code like this...

```
Dim sFileText As String
Dim Files As String
Dim iFileNo As Integer

Dim aray1() As String
Dim aray2() As String

Grid(1).Rows = 1

iFileNo = FreeFile
Files = Text1.Text

Open Files For Input As #iFileNo

Do While Not EOF(iFileNo)

Input #iFileNo, sFileText

aray1 = Split(sFileText, Chr(9))

For i = 0 To UBound(aray1) - 1
' MsgBox aray1(i)
 Grid(1).Rows = Grid(1).Rows + 1

 Grid(1).TextMatrix(Grid(1).Rows - 1, 0) = aray1(0)
 Grid(1).TextMatrix(Grid(1).Rows - 1, 1) = aray1(1)
 Grid(1).TextMatrix(Grid(1).Rows - 1, 2) = aray1(2)
 Grid(1).TextMatrix(Grid(1).Rows - 1, 3) = aray1(3)
 Grid(1).TextMatrix(Grid(1).Rows - 1, 4) = aray1(4)
 Grid(1).TextMatrix(Grid(1).Rows - 1, 5) = aray1(5)
Next i

Loop
```

The Result is Like this (sorry I can't display images) :

36  2012-10-20 08:59:34 1 255 1 0 
36  2012-10-20 08:59:34 1 255 1 0 
36  2012-10-20 08:59:34 1 255 1 0 
36  2012-10-20 08:59:34 1 255 1 0 
36  2012-10-20 08:59:34 1 255 1 0 
110 2012-10-20 09:45:00 1 255 1 0 
110 2012-10-20 09:45:00 1 255 1 0 
110 2012-10-20 09:45:00 1 255 1 0 
110 2012-10-20 09:45:00 1 255 1 0 
110 2012-10-20 09:45:00 1 255 1 0

Is everyone know the code to display only once for each record in the MSFlexGrid ?
It shows 5 times in each records..

P.S : Sorry for Bad English :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of the line that starts the FOR loop, and the line that ends it (the NEXT statement)

You are looping, and there is no need.

Basically, with the FOR NEXT Loop you are adding a new row in the grid, for every element (Column) in the array (aray1)  NOT every row.

Delete those two lines and you should be fine.